# In selenium test cases, how to select the file in input type file

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to select the file from input type= "file" using selenium test cases. So I have followed the below way.

```
browser.element(By.id('fileupload')).click();
```

By adding this line , popup window has been opened. 
   From that window i need to select **document.docx** file from the **D:\files\document.docx** location.

But i dont know how to open the corresponding location and select the file programaticaly in javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Check if this works for your:

```
browser.element(By.id('fileupload')).sendKeys(filepath);
```

Normally when its an input it accepts a direct filepath.

Comment: Hi Anand,  above suggestion works  for me, thank you

Comment: Hi Anand, Now i have facing the below error in my side

 Error: There are some read requests waiting on finished stream
Stack:
 Error: There are some read requests waitng on finished stream
        at module.exports.ChunkStream._end (../node_modules\pngjs-image\node_modules\pngjs\lib\chunkstream.js:100:7)

Can you please suggest how to resolve it ?

Answer (score 1):

As per your question if the *file upload* element includes **input type= "file"** the most easiest and efficient way is :

```
browser.element(By.id('fileupload')).sendKeys("D:\\files\\document.docx");
```